# How to turn off logs for Apache 4.0 (BETA 1)?

Tags: java, apache-cayenne

After upgrading to Cayenne 4 BETA 1, I'm getting lots of logs. How do I turn them off?

For example:

> org.apache.cayenne.log.Slf4jJdbcEventLogger logBeginTransaction
>   org.apache.cayenne.log.Slf4jJdbcEventLogger logCommitTransaction
>   ... etc.

(I believe the methods are different from the previous versions.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods generally are same as in previous version but underlying **API** used by Cayenne has changed from *commons-logging* to *[SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org)*. And JDBC events logger was renamed accordingly.

You can either:

- tune log levels by yourself using logging API. How to do this depends on logging back-end of your choice (e.g. logback, log4j or commons-logging) and is out of Cayenne's scope. If you have some configuration for commons-logging you can learn how to keep it [here](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#slf4jJCL).
- or you can completely disable Cayenne JDBC logging, when you are creating *ServerRuntime*, for example:

```java
ServerRuntime runtime = ServerRuntime.builder()
            .addConfig("your_project.xml")
            .addModule(binder -> binder.bind(JdbcEventLogger.class).to(NoopJdbcEventLogger.class))
            .build();
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked.  However, I'm still seeing "org.apache.cayenne.map.EntityResolver applyDBLayerDefaults" and "org.apache.cayenne.datasource.DriverDataSource logConnect". What is the best way to turn off ALL logs, or at least those appearing?

Comment: As I mentioned above to deal with all logging output you should use logging specific methods, e.g. you can add logback library to your project and make it filter out all cayenne related logs, see [logback documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) for details